# Compile error : Argument not optional in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an error message Argument not optional at below line for the Days function:
I need to calculate the date diff.

```
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("R" & row).Formula = WorksheetFunction.Days(Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("P" & row, "Q" & row))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Days` function requires two parameters, but you have just passed a single parameter (a one row by two column range).  Use:

```
... = WorksheetFunction.Days(Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("P" & row), Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Q" & row))
```